# Onesignal opt-in popup Cordova/Ionic Android fails

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

Unfortunately I have a problem with OneSignal for Ionic.

What is working?:
 - iOS and Android devices accept push messages fine
 - Users show up on Onesignal admin panel just fine
 - I can manually opt-in and opt-out (using window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(true/false);)
 - On iOS I receive a popup asking me to opt-in for push messages.

What is not working:
 - I do not receive the popup on Android devices asking me to opt-in. All users are automatically opt-in ;-)
I spent a few hours reading stackoverflow, onesignal user manuals but no solution is provided.

---

My app.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window.plugins.OneSignal.init("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                                 {googleProjectNumber: "1111111111111"},
                                 notificationOpenedCallback);

  // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
  window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
}, false);
```

I installed the "onesignal-cordova-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Android users are automatically opted into OneSignal push notifications. If you would like to ask permission first you can call `OneSignal.setSubscription(false);` after `OneSignal.init(...)` to keep them from being opted in automatically. Then display your own in app prompt where you call `OneSignal.setSubscription(true);` if they accept.